# Adding function to function.php error 505

Tags: functions, themes

Whenever I try to edit the function.php file of my theme. I get an 505 Error, no matter what function I add it will always give me that error.

Comment: What are the contents of your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Does the error occur *after* you have edited the file, or when you try to access the theme editor inside of WordPress?

Comment: After I edit the file.

Comment: A good question should always show effort and research. And please add your the code you are trying to add

Answer (score 1):

Editing your functions.php file is high risk, specially if it is a theme you acquired through purchasing or downloaded. There a several risks in doing that, firstly, just one simple syntax error, and site crash, like you explained. Secondly, if you upgrade the theme, all your changes will be lost. You won't have that problem if it is your own theme though.

If the theme you are using is not your own, there are two options. One is a child theme, the other is a functionality plugin.

**CHILD THEME**

Child themes are really quick to create, takes less that 5 minutes. You can read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and do some google searches on that subject. Once you have your child theme, create a functions.php file inside the root of your child theme. Inside your that functions.php, add the following and save the file

```
 <?php
// My code goes here. Don't add code outside these php tags

?>
```

That is all you need. You can now add any functions between the php tags.

**FUNCTIONALITY PLUGIN**

This is actually a really good route to take, specially for functions that are not theme specific, things like custom post types, google analytics, short codes etc.

A functionality plugin is also as fast as a child theme. You just need to create a file in your plugin folder and name it something like "my-plugin.php". Open that file and place the following code in there

```
/*
Plugin Name: Your Site's Functionality Plugin
Description: All of the important functionality of your site belongs in this.
Version: 0.1
License: GPL
Author: Your Name
Author URI: yoururl
*/
// Start adding code from here
```

You can now activate your plugin in the back end under plugins.

**A FEW IMPORTANT THINGS TO REMEMBER**

Any syntax error, even one little misplaced or missing or extra character in a functions file will crash your site, full stop.

Don't just dump code in your functions.php. Always check for errors first, and decide if it is theme related code or site related code. Site related code should be in your functionality plugin.

If you haven't already done this, create a local testing site on your pc. Xammplite is a good place to start. The advantage here is, should you crash your site, or test some code, or something unexpected happens, you will not ruin your live site. Fixing errors are also quick, as your theme is on your pc, not on a server

Don't include the opening and closing php tags given in codes you get from the internet. This will give a syntax error, crashing your site. So code like this

```
<?php
function some_function() {
// code to some_function()
}
?>
```

Should be added as

```
function some_function() {
    // code to some_function()
    }
```

Use a program like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to edit or create files in a theme. Notepad++ will show syntaxes, so you actually see syntax errors while coding.

One last thing, don't use the theme editor in the back end. It is really easy to make a mistake adding code in there, crashing your site.

Hope this help to answer your question